# Parsing XML issue

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, uitableview

I have been trying to parse an XML file and all is going well except for one thing.

this is what my XML looks like:

```
<portfolio>
    <item>
        <image url="http://www.google.com" />
        <title>my first title here.</title>
        <desc>my first description here...</desc>
        <date>15/07/2010</date>
        <skills>skills 1, skills 2, skills 3</skills>
    </item>
</portfolio>
```

I have been parsing: title, desc, date, and skills perfectly. The only issue I am having is parsing the image url. I am using this simple parser: https://github.com/robertmryan/Simple-XML-Parser

Anyway this is how I am setting up the element names to parse:

```
parser.elementNames = @[@"image", @"title", @"desc", @"date", @"skills"];
```

Anyway what do I feed into the element name for the image url based upon the XML snippet I gave above?

Thanks!

Edit:
I logged the dictionary it returns after trying the following 3 bits of code:

```
parser.attributeNames = @[@"image url"];
parser.attributeNames = @[@"image"];
parser.attributeNames = @[@"url"];
```

Each one of those (after being parsed), returns a dictionary which I logged as this:

```
dict keys: (
    title,
    skills,
    desc,
    date
)
```

So something is not working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image` element has a `url` attribute so you need to specify that you want the attribute to be parsed out too. Do this by setting the value of the `attributeNames` property on your `parser`.

This parser is really basic though so it has some limitations. Most important for you is that `attributeNames` is only used on the 'main' element (specified with `rowElementName`) so to do what you want to do you will need to edit the parser class to change that.

Comment: Ok. Sorry if I sound like a complete noob here (first time using XML). Does that mean for the attributeNames I set it to "image url" and remove "image" from the elementNames array? I am just a bit confused.

Comment: I expect you just want to add `parser. attributeNames = @[@"url"];`. You should note that I haven't used the library before.

Comment: Ah okay. I tried using this code: parser.attributeNames = @[@"url"];
  
    parser.elementNames = @[@"image", @"title", @"desc", @"date", @"skills"]; but it still doesn't parse the URL.

Comment: Are you logging `parser.items` after each change to view the full set of parsed data ?

Comment: Looking at the source for the parser my earlier suggestion should be correct - but - attributes are only processed for the `rowElementName` element...

Comment: Check out my edit in my OP. Something isn't working right. I put the attribute in the attributeNames and exclude it in elementNames and the logged I posted shows what happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35706/discussion-between-wain-and-ibrad-apps)